# Type mismatch. Required: Result<NewsResponse>! Found: Result<Response<NewsResponse>>?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, sealed-class

I am developing android app and I have implemented success and failure cases in viemodel class but I am getting following mismatch Type mismatch.
Required:
Result!
Found:
Result<Response>

below my NewsViewModel where I have implemented success and failure cases when I am getting data

```
class NewsViewModel(private val repository: NewsRepository) : ViewModel() {


    private var _newsResponse= MutableLiveData<Result<NewsResponse>>()
    // Expose to the outside world
    val news: LiveData<Result<NewsResponse>> = _newsResponse
    @UiThread
    fun getNews() {
         viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {


             try {
                 val response = repository.getNews()
                 _newsResponse.postValue(Result.success(response))
             } catch (ioe: IOException) {
                 _newsResponse.postValue(Result.Failure("[IO] error please retry", ioe))
             } catch (he: HttpException) {
                 _newsResponse.postValue(Result.Failure("[HTTP] error please retry", he))
             }
         }
    }

         }
```

below my NewsRepository.ktclass

```
NewsRepository(
   private val apiInterface:NewsInterface
){

suspend fun getNews() = apiInterface.getNews()


}
```

below my Result class

```
sealed class Result<out T> {
    data class Success<out R>(val value: R): Result<R>()
    data class Failure(
        val message: String?,
        val throwable: Throwable?
    ): Result<Nothing>()
}
```

I want to know where I exactly I am making mistake what I have to do in order to fix that problem

below my news Interface

import com.example.newsworldwide.model.NewsResponse
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.GET
interface NewsInterface {

```
@GET("ApiKey")
suspend fun getNews(): Response<NewsResponse>
```

}

Comment: Can you please post the code for `NewsInterface`?

Comment: @MayurGajra I have added NewsInterface

Comment: What is `Response`  class? Can you add code for that as well? & One more thing `@GET` where does this come from? Retrofit?

Comment: @MayurGajra response come from retrofit import statement

Comment: Can you provide me with `NewsInterface` with import statements? I am getting errors here. I think I've wrong imports.

Comment: @MayurGajra I have added as you told please check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241299/discussion-between-yodgorbek-komilov-and-mayur-gajra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NewsInterface` is returning `Response<NewsResponse>` & in your `NewsViewModel` you're passing it directly to `response` so it becomes  `Result.Success<Response<NewsResponse>>` at the time of posting. That's why this error.

**Solution:**

1. Get value from `body()` of retrofit response class.
2. Make it Non-nullable using(!!) as your `_newsResponse` live-data is accepting `NewsResponse` which is non-nullable. You might want to handle null case here.

So your final code would look something like this.

```
class NewsViewModel(private val repository: NewsRepository) : ViewModel() {


    private var _newsResponse= MutableLiveData<Result<NewsResponse>>()
    // Expose to the outside world
    val news: LiveData<Result<NewsResponse>> = _newsResponse

    @UiThread
    fun getNews() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

            try {
                val response = repository.getNews().body()!! //change this line
                _newsResponse.postValue(Result.Success(response))
            } catch (ioe: IOException) {
                _newsResponse.postValue(Result.Failure("[IO] error please retry", ioe))
            } catch (he: HttpException) {
                _newsResponse.postValue(Result.Failure("[HTTP] error please retry", he))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Mayur Gajra thank you so much for your reply and answer it was great pleasure a receving an answer from you